# RoR: Passing collection to partial won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections, partial

I'm extending some open source RoR project and I have the following problem: The original programmers passed a collection to a partial like this

```
<%= render partial: "option", collection: survey.options %>
```

and then they use it in the partial, e.g. like this

```
<%= option.name %>
```

All that works fine and is understandable when reading this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

A survey also has answer_pairs (with the String fields "answer1" and "answer2") and I try to pass them to another partial like this

```
<%= render partial: "table_head", collection: survey.answer_pairs %>
```

and I try to use it in the partial _table_head.html.erb like this

```
<td><b><%= answer_pair.answer2 %></b></td>
```

But Rails gives me an NameError - undefined local variable or method `answer_pair' for #<#:0x007fa07b9e0098>: app/views/surveys/_table_head.html.erb:1

Could anyone tell me why, please? 
When I also pass "as:" like this

```
<%= render partial: "table_head", collection: survey.answer_pairs, as: :answer_pair %>
```

it recognizes the first answer_pair of the collection, but nothing more. 
It recognizes all the answer_pairs of the collection, if I do it like

```
<% survey.answer_pairs.each do |pair| %>
    <td><b><%= pair.answer2 %></b></td>
<% end %>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The auto generated variable is named after the template, not the collection name. If you access it as `<td><b><%= table_head.answer2 %></b></td>`, then it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! You are right about the name of the auto generated variable, but when I do it like you say it again stops to iterate through the collection after the first answer_pair :( Do have an idea why?